# How to get the shape of a sparse tensor and convert it to list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have some codes of reading datas from a file and use them as the input of a tensorflow network.

```
import tensorflow as tf
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['/home/stuart/Desktop/tfrecords/m_6803.tfrecords'])
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialized_example,
    features={
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'user_behavior': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
    })
label = tf.cast(tf.decode_raw(features['label'], tf.uint8), tf.float32)
user_behavior = tf.cast(features['user_behavior'], tf.float32)
sess = tf.Session()
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
print(user_behavior.get_shape().as_list()) # output: [None]
print(sess.run(tf.shape(user_behavior)) # output: (376), type: Tensor("Shape/Cast:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
```

Now I need to get the shape of the tensor 'user_behavior' because it varies from the files(I have more than one file to read although there is only one here). And then use the shape in defining the weight matrix. The `sess.run(tf.shape())` do work, but it returns the shape as a tensor which could not be used in `tf.Variable([], shape=[])` because the arg `shape` here requires a list. Although I know `tensor.get_shape().as_list()` returns a list, since I use `tf.VarLenFeature()`, it creates a sparse tensor. If I use this method on it, the output will be [None]. So is there a way to get the shape of this sparse tensor and use it to define the shape of another tensor?

Answer (score 0):

Since`user_behavior`is a varlen feature. It will turn into a sparse tensor after `tf.parse_single_example`method.Then you can easily get the shape through `user_behavior.dense_shape` method. For detail description, you can refer to:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/SparseTensor